# How to kill childprocess in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

Created a childprocess using shelljs

```
!/usr/bin/env node

require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/shelljs/global');
   fs = require("fs");  
   var child=exec("sudo mongod &",{async:true,silent:true});

   function on_exit(){
        console.log('Process Exit');
        child.kill("SIGINT");
        process.exit(0)
    }

    process.on('SIGINT',on_exit);
    process.on('exit',on_exit);
```

Child process is still running .. after kill the parent process

Comment: You're running `mongod &` which forks the process and sends it to background. sending **SIGINT** won't kill the actual `mongod` process.

Comment: One more thing, instead of executing `sudo mongod`, exec `mongod` and run your script with `sudo`. You can drop privileges after executing `mongod` (with `process.setuid()` and `process.setgid()`) if you want.

Comment: removed '&' and it worked .... thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/303270/fardjad

Comment: @fardjad, So how to deal with it? We all know what you said. It is written here, no secret https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal. But to deal with it? Do you know?

Comment: @Green Maybe this helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-tree

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you can use node's built in [`child_process.spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), you're able to send a `SIGINT` signal to the child process:

```
var proc = require('child_process').spawn('mongod');
proc.kill('SIGINT');
```

An upside to this is that the main process should hang around until all of the child processes have terminated.

Comment: isn't proc.kill() enough? or do we need proc.kill('SIGINT')?

Comment: i don't remember the specifics of `mongod`, but sending `proc.kill()` is (currently) equivalent to sending `proc.kill('SIGTERM')` (i'm assuming i believed `SIGINT` would shut down `mongod`?). i imagine that one would pick the correct signal for their particular application.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This answer suggests exactly the same what the author of the question already does to kill the process. Nevertheless it gets that many upvotes?

Comment: WRONG! You can't terminate a service you have started in a child process. You can kill child process but cannot terminate a service. That's the problem ` the signal delivered to the child process may not actually terminate the process.` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal

Comment: Thank you, this saved my time! Also, I had a problem that my forked process spawned another processes (with cluster) and ```.kill('SIGINT')``` did the trick and close every child and subchild processes correctly for me in my electron-nodejs application

Comment: This does not kill the actual process on some cases if the option `shell` is `true`

Comment: @fishbone, no it's not the same. Read it again. The answer suggests using `spawn` instead of `exec`.

Comment: @Green - Good point, but in the cases where it works, it is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY thing that has worked for me to kill an `.exec()` child process is to use the npm library `terminate`. Here's how:

```js
const terminate = require('terminate')
terminate(myProcess.pid, err => console.log(err))
```

Where `myProcess` is simply this: `const myProcess = childProcess.exec(...)`.

You can install terminate with: `yarn add terminate`

This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// only windows

const module_child_process = require('child_process');
let proc = module_child_process.spawn("cmd"); 
let pid = proc.pid;
let cmd = `wmic process where parentprocessid=${pid} get ProcessId`;
let out = module_child_process.execSync(cmd);
let stdout = out.toString();
let pids=[];
let lines = stdout.split("\n");
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
{
    try 
    {
        let data = lines[i].toString();
        let val = parseInt(data.trim());
        if (!isNaN(val))
        {
            //console.log(val.toString());
            pids.push(val);
        }
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) 
{
    module_process.kill(pids[i]);
    /* or    
    let cmd = `taskkill /pid ${pids[i].toString()} /T /F`;
    console.log(cmd);
    module_child_process.execSync(cmd);
    */
}

proc.kill();
proc = null;
```