# How do I kill forked child process after use?

Tags: node.js, fork, child-process

I have this function and fork a child process to run a heavy work on background. The `work` module sends message after it completes the work. How do I kill or close the forked process?

```
function doWork() {
    var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/work');
    child.on('message', function(m) {
      console.log('completed: ' + m);
      // try to kill child process when work signals it's done
      child.kill('SIGHUP');
    });
    child.send({
      msg: 'do work',
      name: self.myname
    });
}
```

-edit-

I tried `child.kill('SIGHUP')` and `child.kill();` when work signals it's done. I seems didn't kill the process. If I do `ps | grep node`, it still shows the work process is alive. What am I missing?

Comment: Right in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal)  `child.kill()`.

Comment: I tried that but it seems not working. when I do `child.kill()` and check if process is killed by `ps | grep node` and I still see the work process is alive

Comment: It depends upon your process and what signals it may be catching and handling on its own, but you may want to send it `child.kill('SIGKILL')` or `child.kill('SIGTERM')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill childprocess in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187184/how-to-kill-childprocess-in-nodejs)

Comment: @PaulSweatte Probably not, this is specific to a 'forked' child which behaves differently than other children. I am also having this issue.

Comment: I guess, you need to kill sub-process too. There are some packages available eg treekill.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late!

You can try to get pid of the forked child and pass it to child as reference and when job is done send pid along with the completion signal and you can kill the process based on pid.

```
function doWork() {
    var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/work');
    child.on('message', function(m) {
        //try to pass pid along with the signal from child to parent
        console.log('completed: ' + m);
        //killing child process when work signals it's done
        process.kill(m.pid);
    });
    child.send({
        msg: 'do work',
        name: self.myname,
        pid : child.pid // passing pid to child
    });
}
```