# How do I kill a child process

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to kill a child process started using exec? Believe it or not, not all applications just *end* (such as ls) but continue unless you exit them using the control-c shortcut. Is there a way to replicate this via code. I want to kill the process. Here is some code that initializes the process, if that helps.

```
const notcp = require("child_process");
notcp.exec("./IAmAnAppThatDoesntJustStop.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
// 
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with just calling .kill() on the returned process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dead set on using `.exec()` to execute your script then, no there is [no (easy) built-in](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) way to end the processes you just started. If you're flexible and can use the `.spawn()` function instead, things change and you checkout [the following question/answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187184/how-to-kill-childprocess-in-nodejs).

If you still want to use `.exec()` maybe try using a library such as [Taskkill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/taskkill) or [Fkill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fkill) to simplify the complexity of implementing such a feature?

Comment: How do I get a process number?

Comment: If using ```spawn``` or ```exec``` you can find the pid by using the return value of the called function.

```const myProcess = spawn ( cmd , args , { cwd : path } );
myProcess.pid```

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY thing that has worked for me to kill an `.exec()` child process is to use the npm library `terminate` after trying every single signal with kill none of them worked. But `terminate` did. Here's how:

```js
const terminate = require('terminate')
terminate(myProcess.pid, err => console.log(err))
```

Where `myProcess` is simply this: `const myProcess = childProcess.exec(...)`. You don't need to use `{ detached: true }` on the child process, it's not necessary.

You can install terminate with: `yarn add terminate` (it's not my project)

This worked perfectly.